# Probability Distribution Function $W=X+Y$

Tags: probability

$(X,Y) \sim f(x,y)=2x \space (0 \leq x \leq 1, |y| < x^2)$

$W = X+Y$

pdf $f_w(w)$

how do I get the value $f_w(w)$ ?

Is the span divided ? I am not sure .... T.T

I think x,y are not independent, it's not iid. am a right?

Answer (score 2):

No, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent; you must integrate the two-dimensional PDF.

**Hints.** $W$ ranges from $0$ to $2$, as you can tell if you draw out the space of $X$ and $Y$ on an ordinary $x$-$y$ plot.  (It should look like a squat horn that is symmetric around the $x$-axis.)  For $W < 1/4$, the space is broken up into two parts: the part nearer the tip of the horn, and the part nearer the lower part of the bell.  For $W \geq 1/4$, the space is all in one part; for $W = 1/4$ exactly, the space is tangent to the lower curve.

To determine the limits of integration, you need to solve for $x$ in

$$
x^2+x = w
$$

for the upper curve, and

$$
-x^2+x = w
$$

for the lower curve, both for $w = 0$ to $2$.  Drawing this out should help you determine which roots are lower limits of integration, which roots are upper limits, and which are neither.  The absolute upper limit of integration, of course, is $x = 1$.

As an example, the larger solution of the upper curve for $w = 1/4$ is $x = \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$, so we can write

$$
f_W(1/4) = \int_{x=\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}}^1 2x \, dx
$$

You can find a depiction of the situation here:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oufzohxbom

Comment: but Does this use pdf(probability distribution function) concept??

Comment: Sure: You are integrating a PDF in two dimensions (for the variables $X$ and $Y$) to obtain the PDF in one dimension (for the variable $W$).

Comment: but the result of pdf is expressed in kind of equation, isn't it? or could you explain more in detail?